# Download a file from a URL to a user accessible location

Tags: http, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am building an app using [Nativescript/Angular 2](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/introduction.html)

I want to be able to download a file from a URL and save it to the device in a location the average user would have no problems finding it. I believe downloads would be the best place for this on both `iOS` and `Android`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The file can be any file type, not just an image. So mainly `spreadsheet`, `word document`, `pdf`, `png`, `jpg`, etc.

I have searched online and through the documentation. The documentation describes a method called [getFile](http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http#get-file-from-url-by-default-the-file-will-be-saved-in-documents-folder) which gets a file and saves it to your device.

I have implemented this in my code as follows:

```
download (id) {
  console.log('Download Started');
  getFile("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/master/apps/tests/logo.png").then(function (r) {
    console.log(r.path);
  }, function (e) {
    //// Argument (e) is Error!
  });
}
```

The problem with this is that it saves it to a non-user accessible location such as:

```
/data/user/0/com.myapp.example/files/logo.png
```

Update:

I have also tried specifying the path directly with:

```
fs.knownFolders.documents();
```

However, this method gets the documents folder for the current application that is NOT accessible by the user or external applications

Answer (score 15):

After some unsuccessful attempts, I finally found how to save file to user "Downloads" folder (something like sdcard/Download). You can use android.os.Environment method to get this folder.

Add this in your component:

```
import { getFile } from 'tns-core-modules/http';
import * as fileSystem from "tns-core-modules/file-system";
import { isAndroid } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { alert } from "tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs";

declare var android;
```

<...>

```
public download (url, fileName) {
    if (isAndroid) {
        const permissions = require("nativescript-permissions");
        permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "I need these permissions because I'm cool")
            .then(() => {
                let downloadedFilePath = fileSystem.path.join(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath(), fileName);
                getFile(url, downloadedFilePath).then(resultFile => {
                    alert({
                        title: 'Saved!',
                        okButtonText: 'OK',
                        message: `File saved here:\n${resultFile.path}`
                    });
                }, error => {
                    alert({
                        title: 'Error',
                        okButtonText: 'OK',
                        message: `${error}`
                    });
                });
            });
    }
}
```

What else you should know:

1) There is no any kind of download indicator, standard system download bar also not appears, and I don't know how to solve this.

2) For iOS you may try to use

```
const filePath = fileSystem.path.join(fileSystem.knownFolders.ios.downloads().path, fileName);
getFile(url, filePath).then((resultFile) => {}, (error) => {});
```

I think, it's the shame that NS docs don't talk straight, that you can't save files in user accessible location only with NS functions. I figured it out only when I read comments in file /node_modules/tns-core-modules/file-system/file-system.d.ts

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

To get it working on iPhone, you can do the following (TypeScript):

```js
import { knownFolders, path } from "tns-core-modules/file-system";

let destination = path.join(knownFolders.documents(), "file_name.txt");
// logic to save your file here ...
// the important thing is that you have to save your file in knownFolders.documents()
```

Then in `Info.plist`, you have to add the following permissions:

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Now if you go to your iPhone's `Files` app > `On My iPhone` > `Your App's Name`, you should see the file there.

Basically, the `Documents` folder is a private folder inside your application's directory that only you can see. However, when you enable the two permissions above, it allows file sharing so that your user can access the folder and its contents.

Answer (score 1):

The same documentation says that you can specify the file location like this:

```
download (id) {
  console.log('Download Started');
  var folder = fs.knownFolders.documents();
  var file = fs.path.join(folder.path, "logo.png");
  var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/master/apps/tests/logo.png"
  getFile(url, file).then(function (r) {
    console.log(r.path);
  }, function (e) {
    //// Argument (e) is Error!
  });
}
```

> disclaimer: never tried it myself, just read the docs ...

Comment: I was aware of this, the fs.knownFolders.documents() method gets the documents folder for the current application that is NOT accessible by the user or external applications.

Comment: Not being able to specify the file location and the location being private to the application seem like two different problems to me. In any case, you just have to specify a public path instead of using `fs.knownFolders.documents()`. I think `fs.knownFolders.ios.downloads()`should give you the downloads folder of ios, but there's no equivalent for android or others, so you'll have to build your own

Comment: I have also tried that path on ios, doesnt work. This is the reason I am posting on stack overflow for some help.

Comment: You might have to handle each platform separately - relatively easy with {N}. On the android the only other publicly accessible folder are the SD card (internal and external) storage folders.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a filesystem path directly, like this:

```
var folder = fs.Folder.fromPath('/sdcard/Download');
```

Note that `/sdcard/Download` will only work on Android; you can replace it with whatever (publicly accessible) folder you want to save your data to.

There doesn't yet seem to be a cross-platform way to choose a folder path, so you'll have to work out something manually. See [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/589) for more.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is 3 years ago but in case you have the same issue, I hope this solution will save time for you.

I solved the same issue by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside the AndroidManifest.xml file
follow the thread [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8203#issue-539121967)

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an older thread, but perhaps this can help someone:

If you use `currentApp()`, instead of `documents()`, you can access the folder you need.  For example:

```
var directories = fs.knownFolders.currentApp();
var folder = directories.getFolder('./nameofaccessiblefolder');
```